# ReactJS doesn't render all JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I'm building a sign in page in ReactJs. I'm new to the software, so I may have used HTML instead of JSX. My ReactJS code in signIn.js is below:

```js
const input = (
  <div class="omrs-input-group">
     <label class="omrs-input-underlined">
        <input required style="height:55px" id="nameFirst" />
           <span class="omrs-input-label">First Name</span>
           <span class="omrs-input-helper" id="alertFirst">Please type in your first name</span>
           <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z"/><circle cx="15.5" cy="9.5" r="1.5"/><circle cx="8.5" cy="9.5" r="1.5"/><path d="M11.99 2C6.47 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.47 10 9.99 10C17.52 22 22 17.52 22 12S17.52 2 11.99 2zM12 20c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8zm-5-6c.78 2.34 2.72 4 5 4s4.22-1.66 5-4H7z"/></svg>
     </label>
   <br/>
        
</div>
)  


ReactDOM.render(
  input,
  document.getElementById('firstNameForm')
)
```

When I try to render this, the warning I get is
`Uncaught Error: Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev environment for the full error message and additional helpful warnings.` For debugging purposes, I tried to render

```js
const input = (
   <h1>Hello World!</h1>
)
ReactDOM.render(
   input,
   document.getElementById('firstNameForm')
)
```

and it renders onto the screen. What is my error?
Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: You should probably heed the error and use the development version of React while developing...

Answer (score 1):

The style attribute in react expects an object value not a string.

```
style={{height: "55px"}}
```

This should fix your issue.

Code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gevqap

Comment: Needless sir. @ProgrammingMaestro